# C , regarding pointers (or pointers to pointers?), **, and malloc

Tags: c, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

As said in title, I have a question regarding using * twice, like in the main function of the following code. it DOES run, but I don't understand why using ** is right here. What i want is an array of SPPoints , sized n, where parr is the base adress. Why is ** right and * wrong in this case? thanks.

SPPoint code:

```
struct sp_point_t
{
    double* data;
    int dim;
    int index;
};

SPPoint* spPointCreate(double* data, int dim, int index)
{
    if (data == NULL || dim <= 0 || index < 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    SPPoint* point = malloc(sizeof(*point));
    if (point == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    point->data = (double*)malloc(dim * sizeof(*data));
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        point->data[i] = data[i];
    }
    point->dim = dim;
    point->index = index;
    return point;
}
```

And this is the main function:

```
int main()
{
    int n, d, k;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &d, &k);
    double* darr = malloc(d * sizeof(double));
    if (darr == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    SPPoint** parr = malloc(n * sizeof(SPPoint*));
    if (parr == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
            scanf(" %lf", &darr[j]);
        }
        parr[i] = spPointCreate(darr, d, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `SPPoint**  parr;` is a pointer to (an array of) pointer(s)

Comment: `SPPoint* spPointCreate(...)` BTW: SPPoint is *not* typedeffed. Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: It is in the header file, sorry for not including that.

Comment: It doesn't matter *where* it is: in C a struct definition is **not** equivalent to a typeffed struct.

Comment: I see, this is interesting because my course staff gave us the header file with the following line: (  typedef struct sp_point_t SPPoint; ), and told us we need to have the struct definition like that in the C file. So if its typedeffed in the header file, does it has to be like that in the C file as well?

Comment: The question text says you want an array of SPPoint, size `n` . But the code creates `n` number of arrays of SPPoint, each of size `1`.   Which do you actually want?

Comment: @M.M I was aiming for the former, however i ran into a problem getting the sizeof(SPPoint) in the main file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An array can behave similarly to a pointer. For instance,  int a [] is very similar to int* a. Each function in SPPoint returns a pointer to a SPPoint struct.  An array of pointers to SPPoint can be written as a pointer to a pointer to SPPoint. With the malloc command, you are designating a certain amount of memory (enough to hold n pointers to SPPoint) for storage of pointers to SPPoint structs.

Not all pointers are arrays, however. SPPoint**  parr is acting as an array holding pointers to single structs of type SPPoint.

Arrays can behave differently from pointers, especially when used for strings.

The reason why it is advantageous to use pointers to SPPoint (as you are now) is that you can view or modify a single element without having to copy the entire struct.

Comment: An array can not be thought of as a pointer, any more than an int can be thought of as a double

Comment: ... indeed, confusing arrays with pointers leads to all manner of misunderstanding and accompanying mistakes.

Comment: When you use the words "very similar" you should also explain why they are not same IMHO.

Comment: @M.M an int and a double are encoded differently, and represent different data. There is almost no situation where they are synonymous. A pointer and an array both store memory addresses, and can mean the exact same thing. That is a false analogy. I edited the answer though.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added a sentence, although this was not a situation in which the difference was important.

Comment: @babon I added a practical warning. I don't think going down further into implementation details would be helpful though.

Comment: @Rusty, you're still not getting it.  Arrays and pointers are completely different things.  ***No*** pointer is an array, nor does a pointer ever act as an array, or an array behave similarly to a pointer.  What does happen is that when an expression of an array type is evaluated, the result is a pointer to the first element of the array.  Of course, such a pointer then acts exactly like a pointer.  This turns out to be fairly important to understand, as many things about C seem inconsistent if you do not grasp that.

Comment: @Rusty an array does not store memory addresses (unless it's an array of pointers). An array *has* an address, but so does an int, and any other object

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was referring to what is stored in a pointer or an array: the memory address of some piece of data, sometimes another memory address. I understand they are not the same thing, but I fail to see how arrays, which decay when passed by value, have no similarity and no similar function to pointers, which C passes to a function which takes an array as input. Any program in C can be rewritten to not include a single square bracket (with significant obfuscation), which wouldn't be possible if pointers had no similarity to arrays, and filled no similar roles.

Comment: As @M.M. said, arrays *do not* store memory addresses, except in the special case that their elements are pointers.  The objections you are raising revolve around some of the very misunderstandings that I referred to earlier.  Among them: (i) no C function accepts an array as an argument; (ii) the indexing operator (`[]`) is technically a *pointer* operator, not an array operator.  You didn't raise this one, but another one we often see around here is the incorrect expectation that a 2D array corresponds to a so-called double pointer.  This is also why C has no whole-array assignment.

Answer (score 0):

When using a dynamically-allocated array, it's usually "handled" by having a pointer to the first element of the array, and also having some method of knowing the length, such as explicitly storing the length, or having an end sentinel.

So for a dynamically allocated array of `SPPoint *` as you have in your code, a pointer to the first one of those has type `SPPoint * *`

Your existing code creates an array of `SPPoint *`, i.e. an array of pointers. Each of those pointers points to one dynamically-allocated instance of `SPPoint`, i.e. you have separate allocations for each entry.

This is viable but you indicate that you instead wanted an array of `SPPoint`, in which case a pointer to the first element has type `SPPoint *`.

In order to have such an array, it is a single memory allocation.  So you will need to redesign your `spPointCreate` function. Currently that allocates memory for and initializes only a single `SPPoint`. Instead you want to separate the allocation from the initialization, since you only need one allocation but you need multiple initializations. Your program logic will read something like:

- Allocate one block of memory big enough for `n` `SPPoint`s
- Initialize each `SPPoint` inside the allocated space

If you have tried this but got stuck then post a new question showing your code and explaining where you got stuck.